# An error ocurred while starting the kernel when I used tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kernel, spyder

When I start to training data, this error occurred. And then I can not do anything.

"
**An error ocurred while starting the kernel**
"

```
   2022 11:23:16.546865: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance‑critical operations: AVX AVX2
    To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
    2022 11:23:16.860791: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21670 MB memory: ‑> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
    2022 11:23:16.873446: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
    2022 11:23:18.625116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8302
```

I have already tried to update anaconda, spyder ,spyder-kernels, Ipython....
But this error still on there.

Answer (score 0):

These are just the Information and Warning messages as these are prefixed with `I` for Information and `W` for warnings, else if this was the error message, these would be prefixed with `E`.

You can suppress these (Informational) `I` messages using the below code on top of your code beginning.

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
```

Please have a look at this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841636/loading-tensorflow-model-on-local-machine/61895645#61895645).